# I need to pass arrayString or arrayList to whtsapp through Intents?

Tags: android

[My whatsapp is stopped and doing nothing when I am clicking send button, not even showing toast which I had typed in catch section.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybDBR.png)
here is my code:

```
String[] arrStr1=new String[finalList.size()];
    finalList.toArray(arrStr1);

       // String smsNumber = "9212197079"; //without '+'
        try {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();//"android.intent.action.MAIN");
            //sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, arrStr1);
                          // sendIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,finalList);

           // sendIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error/n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: You need to give us more information e.g. what the intention is, what the list is of etc. Sending anything other than a phone number to WhatApp sounds like it's not doable as why might WhatsApp allow you to send an array? What might the array be? I can't even think what it might be.

Comment: finalList is an ListArray which contain array of string like: "aa","bb","cc". Then I copy ListArray(finalList) to String[] and then trying to pass through Intent.     But the problem is arising that whatsapp send btn is not working while I am pressing it after selecting particular contact .

Answer (score 0):

Ohh!!! I resolved the issue here is the correct code...

```
 StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
        String[] arrStr=new String[finalList.size()];
        finalList.toArray(arrStr);

        for(i=0;i<arrStr.length;i++){
            str.append(arrStr[i]);
            str.append("\n");
        }



           // String smsNumber = "9212197079"; //without '+'
            try {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();//"android.intent.action.MAIN");
                //sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, str.toString());
                // sendIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,finalList);

               // sendIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error/n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```